# Why doesn't list count() method return 2 from the list created with zip()?

Tags: python, list, count

Here is my code. My question is with the last two `print` statements.

```
topping = ['pepperoni', 'pineapple', 'cheese', 'sausage', 'olives', 'anchovies', 
           'mushrooms']
prices = [2,6,1,3,2,7,2]

num_pizzas = len(topping)
pizzas = list(zip(prices, topping))

# this makes is sort by price from least to greatest
pizzas.sort()

# this prints the cheapest which is the first in the list
cheapest_pizza = pizzas[0]

# this prints the last thing in the list
priciest_pizza = pizzas[-1]

# this prints the first 3 options
three_cheapest = pizzas[:3]

num_two_dollar_slices = prices.count(2)
#this prints 3 $2 prices
print(num_two_dollar_slices)

# Why does this print 0? I would think that it should print 3 as well
num_of_two = pizzas.count(2)
print(num_of_two)
```

Comment: `2` is not an element of `pizzas`. `count` doesn't count elements of elements.

Comment: `pizzas` is a list of 2-element tuples.  The number of `2`s in that list is zero, because there are no integers in the list at all.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `pizzas` list, after the zip and the sort it looks like this:

`[(1, 'cheese'), (2, ' mushrooms'), (2, 'olives'), (2, 'pepperoni'), (3, 'sausage'), (6, 'pineapple'), (7, 'anchovies')]`

Each object is a tuple, and you are trying to count an integer.

Instead you can count the `prices` list since it's the original, or you can write a simple loop that will count the number 2:

```
counter = 0
for price, topping in pizzas:
    if price == 2:
        counter += 1
print(counter)
```

Or of course put it in a function for a generic solution.

Comment: Thanks! makes sense now! Still learning python. Def helps

Comment: @svlad4560 I'm glad it helped :)
Make sure you mark it as the correct answer for people with similar problems in the future.